# Method not found Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications.MessageReceivedNotification

Tags: c#, owin, openid-connect

Recently i've updated packages in an mvc project with owin to 4.0.0
Now up until now I was able to solve a lot of issues with this upgrade (other packages that needed upgrading etc)

But currently I'm stuck on this exception:

```
Method not found: 'System.Func`2<Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications.MessageReceivedNotification`2<Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnectMessage,Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions>,System.Threading.Tasks.Task> Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications.get_MessageReceived()'.
```

I've tried googling, I've tried putting a breakpoint on the inflicted class (constructor get's hit but the method that throws the exception never gets hit even)

Anyone has a clue on what to try next? Or even better on how to fix this one?

```
 protected override async Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
    {
        if (Options.CallbackPath.HasValue && Options.CallbackPath != (Request.PathBase + Request.Path))
        {
            return null;
        }

        OpenIdConnectMessage openIdConnectMessage = null;

        if (string.Equals(Request.Method, "POST", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.ContentType)
            && Request.ContentType.StartsWith("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            && Request.Body.CanRead)
        {
            if (!Request.Body.CanSeek)
            {
                //this._logger.WriteVerbose("Buffering request body");
                // Buffer in case this body was not meant for us.
                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                Request.Body = memoryStream;
            }

            var form = await Request.ReadFormAsync();
            Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            openIdConnectMessage = new OpenIdConnectMessage(form);
        }

        if (openIdConnectMessage == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        ExceptionDispatchInfo authFailedEx = null;
        try
        {
            var messageReceivedNotification = new MessageReceivedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions>(this.Context, this.Options)
            {
                ProtocolMessage = openIdConnectMessage
            };

            await this.Options.Notifications.MessageReceived(messageReceivedNotification);
            if (messageReceivedNotification.HandledResponse)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (messageReceivedNotification.Skipped)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // runtime always adds state, if we don't find it OR we failed to 'unprotect' it this is not a message we should process.
            AuthenticationProperties properties = null;
            if (properties == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // We can't await inside a catch block, capture and handle outside.
            authFailedEx = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(exception);
        }

        if (authFailedEx != null)
        {
            //Refresh the configuration for exceptions that may be caused by key rollovers.The user can also request a refresh in the notification.
            if (this.Options.RefreshOnIssuerKeyNotFound && authFailedEx.SourceException.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException))
                {
                    this.Options.ConfigurationManager.RequestRefresh();
                }

            var authenticationFailedNotification = new AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions>(this.Context, this.Options)
            {
                ProtocolMessage = openIdConnectMessage,
                Exception = authFailedEx.SourceException
            };
            await this.Options.Notifications.AuthenticationFailed(authenticationFailedNotification);
            if (authenticationFailedNotification.HandledResponse)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (authenticationFailedNotification.Skipped)
            {
                return null;
            }

            authFailedEx.Throw();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The above code is the least amount of code needed to make this error occur, as soon as the code uses anything that comes from options.notifications the application immediately crashes with a method not found exception.

Notification property has been setup as follows:

```
 Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                 {
                     RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                     {
                         if (Startup.IsApiRequest(context.Request))
                         {
                             context.HandleResponse();
                             return Task.FromResult(0);
                         }
                         context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = redirectUri;
                         context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri;
                         return Task.FromResult(0);
                     },
                     AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                     {
                         context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
                         context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception

                         return Task.FromResult(0);
                     },
                     AuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
                     {
                         var userIdentity = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                         userIdentity = userIdentity.TransformClaims();

                         context.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                             userIdentity,
                             context.AuthenticationTicket.Properties
                         );

                         return Task.FromResult(0);
                     },
                     SecurityTokenReceived = context => Task.FromResult(0),
                 }
             });
```

Little fyi I'm not the original developer of this code....

Comment: they changed namespaces in several places, for instance 
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect instead of (in addition to) Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols

Comment: So the easiest solution could be removing all the usings and auto fix them with Resharper

Comment: anyway, I've just upgraded without any runtime issues, so can try to inspect your code if you add a piece to the question.

Comment: I've added the exact location of the code where I pinpointed it to crash on me, i've omitted a lot of code that handles the claims etc.

Comment: Hard to say where without seen your exact set of usings, but I still believe (and your error message confirms that) you have somewhere `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnectMessage` and somewhere `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMessage`. The first one has to be totally removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
```

with

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
```

everywhere in your code. That should solve the issue.

Comment: If I do that I get a compiler error so i'm pretty sure that's not correct.

Comment: My comment actually made me start thinking about why that namespace wasn't available, turns out I didn't have that package installed in that specific library, installed it and updated all references to the namespace you said. But still the same error unfortunately.

Comment: And with deeper digging, yet another package seemed to be missing: Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect, and by adding this it now finally works. I'll mark this answer as the correct one since it led to figuring out what was wrong.